# Best way to embed an IRC client in a webpage

Tags: html, irc

I'm looking for a good, free, preferrably open source, IRC client to be embedded in a web page.

The obvious requirements of supporting most browsers, if requiering a plug-in it should be a plug-in that is allready widley deployed and it should not put too much strain on the webserver serving the page.

Comment: Search google for "CGI IRC" if you want IRC clients that run on the webserver.  Otherwise, there is at least on Java IRC client that's embeddable (runs on the user workstation).  Mibbit is a very good IRC client that runs on the webserver.  At any rate, this isn't a programming question - try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions for other forums where you can get better help.

Comment: How is this not a programming question? I'm looking for a component that can be used in a programming project...

Comment: CGI IRC is written in perl and breaks with older proxies. Kiwi is way more advisable not using ancient perl but ECMAscript vulgo JS.

Answer (score 4):

Not really a programming question, but [Mibbit](http://mibbit.com/) is quite capable, I've used it for a few different applications, it's always worked well.

Note that it will work best if your channel is on one of [the networks listed here that support WEBIRC](http://mibbit.com/networks/).

Answer (score 3):

An iframe can be embedded.
http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=channel_name

Answer (score 3):

A commonly used open source platform is [QwebIRC](http://qwebirc.org/). In python with a javascript frontend, but has all sorts of packaging issues. [KiwiIRC](http://kiwiirc.com/) seems really interesting but I haven't tried it yet so I can't vouch for it. KiwiIRC is all javascript. Both can be embeded in an iframe or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen these before, but I have never really liked them. I think the best overall one was [Mibbit](http://www.mibbit.com/). I think the best way to go about it would be to ask the user to install a client and use the irc:// linking syntax to launch a native client.

Answer (score 1):

I assume a java applet would pass the multiplatform / Browser requirement ?

[Pjirc](http://www.pjirc.com/)   Its not one ive used personally, but i have seen a fair few sites using it.

Comment: It seems the last release of Pjirc was 2004. Why is that?