# Embedding a chat onto an html website

Tags: javascript, html, chat, skype

I have recently read some threads about embedding chat like skype chat into websites but most of them were outdated. So do you have ideas about a fast way (if it's possible) of embedding a chat into a website? Is there a way of embedding known chat engines? like skype, ebuddy, digsby, yahoo chat.. etc. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get a mysql database and a webserver with php
2. Program a script on serverside which can do 2 things:

a: Save user inputs to the database
b: Echo all changes since last pull to the user

Then you just need to create a client (in this case the website) with an form which uses AJAX to push new messages to the server and a timer to pull new messages.

For that you just need to learn Javascript and PHP.

(A Java plugin would work too but there have recently been some security leaks *g*)

And if you are too lazy to learn coding just use something like Joomla or Webspell, they should have chat plugins you can download.

Comment: I am disappointed on how this thread took a negative vote. Not all people are programmers so why not trying to be more helpful with them? I am trying to find ways to help my self making things more easier and eventually help others who may are looking for the very same thing. 

we are not in a teaching class and there should be no limitation in the help offered. 

@th3falc0n thanks for your answer... I'll check it out.. if it's something "easy" I will give it a try.. but are there any ready codes for such things?

Comment: I'have made the whole html website by my own.. but engaging to Javascript and PHP it's kinda difficult.. there is not time and I making a website to run my business better. Thank you again.

Comment: What you can do also: You can use a existing only chat provider and just link to a chatroom (IRC for example)

Comment: BTW in this site there are no threads covering this matter!! Embedded chat is something very important for lot of people.. there should be a post in which all possible answers would be there!! I tried to make such a post!

Comment: So there are no ways of embedding chat providers like skype into an html website? It would be something really good!Thank again .. your answers would be voted up If I had the "reputation" but I am new here!

Comment: I don't think there is a premade way to integrate proprietary things like skype into a website. You should really take a look at things like IRC or code a chat by your own. It's not really difficult. (IRC integration related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778430/best-way-to-embed-an-irc-client-in-a-webpage )

Comment: Why did u uncheck my answer? mibbit was just mentioned in the post I gave you. :(

Comment: I didn't uncheck.. I did check also the other answer... perhaps It allows only one answer... so it will be yours. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the Mibbit Web IRC Chat http://mibbit.com/ . It can embedd a lot of IRC-Networks in your website.